# Are questions about non-sport rules of a sport federation on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Many sport federations have rules that establish how the federation work:

- Rules when creating a local club
- Rules regarding the sale of equipment
- Rules regarding how federation leaders are chosen
- etc

Are such questions on-topic on this site?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say they're on topic so long as they're about a notable federation. For example, it's probably not interesting to anyone else how my local cricket league chooses its leaders, but it certainly is interesting how the ICC or FIFA choose their leaders.

Answer (score 3):

[We've had previous discussions on what we require in terms of "notability"](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/897).

If these regulations are important to a great number of people or to significant sports-related events, they are likely to be on-topic.

If they are heavily localised, limited to a small and relatively insignificant audience, they are likely to be off-topic.

Compare with the [autograph-identification](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autograph-identification) tag. We have deemed these off-topic not because the sports or signers are not important or because memorabilia aren't part of sports lore, but because the questions are so limited in usefulness to the broader user base that they are simply not within the intended scope of Stack Exchange as a network, and hence not within the scope of Sports SE in particular, alongside other topicality issues that are more likely to arise in such questions.